# Interpolating a string into a regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to substitute the value of a string into my regular expression in Ruby. Is there an easy way to do this? For example:

```
foo = "0.0.0.0"
goo = "here is some other stuff 0.0.0.0" 
if goo =~ /value of foo here dynamically/
  puts "success!"
end
```

Comment: Are you trying to see if foo is a substring of goo? I don't think it's clear what you're asking.

Comment: If so, goo.include?(foo) is enough!

Comment: No, I wasn't trying to see if foo is a substring of goo; I also needed to do some capturing as well, hence include didn't work.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

Same as string insertion.

```
if goo =~ /#{Regexp.quote(foo)}/
#...
```

Comment: `Regexp#quote` is an alias of `Regexp#escape` cf. https://devdocs.io/ruby~3.2/regexp#method-c-quote

Answer (score 143):

Note that the [`Regexp.quote`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-quote) in [Jon L.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150115/211563) is important!

```
if goo =~ /#{Regexp.quote(foo)}/
```

If you just do the "obvious" version:

```
if goo =~ /#{foo}/
```

then the periods in your match text are treated as regexp wildcards, and `"0.0.0.0"` will match `"0a0b0c0"`.

Note also that if you really just want to check for a substring match, you can simply do

```
if goo.include?(foo)
```

which doesn't require an additional quoting or worrying about special characters.

Comment: Note that the reverse (not using `.quote()`) can also be useful if you're looking to construct a regex using a string.

Comment: "if you really just want to check for a substring match, you can simply do `if goo.include?(foo)`" => True when you're interested in checking for existence.  If you're interested in replacing and already using String.gsub, then Regexp.quote may be your only option.

Comment: Just to add on to Jesse in case it isn't obvious, this means just passing the string of characters you don't need escaped to `Regexp.new` or `Regexp.compile`.

Comment: Thank you for the useful explanation of why we might want to use Regexp.quote

Answer (score 7):

Probably `Regexp.escape(foo)` would be a starting point, but is there a good reason you can't use the more conventional expression-interpolation: `"my stuff #{mysubstitutionvariable}"`?

Also, you can just use `!goo.match(foo).nil?` with a literal string.

Answer (score 6):

```
Regexp.compile(Regexp.escape(foo))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a limited but useful other answer:

I discovered I that I can easily insert into a regex without using Regexp.quote or Regexp.escape if I just used single quotes on my input string: (an IP address match)

```
IP_REGEX = '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'

my_str = "192.0.89.234 blahblah text 1.2, 1.4" # get the first ssh key 
# replace the ip, for demonstration
my_str.gsub!(/#{IP_REGEX}/,"192.0.2.0") 
puts my_str # "192.0.2.0 blahblah text 1.2, 1.4"
```

single quotes only interpret \\ and \'.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Single_quotes

This helped me when i needed to use the same long portion of a regex several times. 
Not universal, but fits the question example, I believe.

Comment: i'm curious what will be thought of my post here, but i doubt it will be seen so far down here now.

Answer (score 2):

Use Regexp.new:

```
if goo =~ Regexp.new(foo) # Evaluates to /0.0.0.0/
```

Answer (score -2):

```
foo = "0.0.0.0"
goo = "here is some other stuff 0.0.0.0" 

puts "success!" if goo =~ /#{foo}/
```

Comment: No, this will give an erroneous "true" for "here is some other stuff 070x0!0", because the dots are regexp wildcards.