# How to test puts with partial match in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

`expect{test_method}.to output(test_str).to_stdout` works, but only when I use `print` in my method. If I use `puts` then the test fails because `puts` adds `\n` to the end (I know that this is the difference between `print` and `puts`).

So is there a way to test that the output includes rather than equals a

certain string?

`expect(STDOUT).to receive(:puts).and include(test_str)`, which is what I would guess, doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend trying a regular expression:

```
expect {test_method}.to output(/#{Regexp.quote(test_str)}/).to_stdout
```

There were examples provided in [the rspec blog](http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#new-output-matcher) when this feature was announced that may help:

```
expect { print "foo" }.to output("foo").to_stdout
expect { print "foo" }.to output(/fo/).to_stdout
expect { warn  "bar" }.to output(/bar/).to_stderr
```

The [`output` matcher docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers#output-instance_method) include more examples:

```
expect { print 'foo' }.to output.to_stdout
expect { print 'foo' }.to output('foo').to_stdout
expect { print 'foo' }.to output(/foo/).to_stdout

expect { do_something }.to_not output.to_stdout

expect { warn('foo') }.to output.to_stderr
expect { warn('foo') }.to output('foo').to_stderr
expect { warn('foo') }.to output(/foo/).to_stderr

expect { do_something }.to_not output.to_stderr

expect { system('echo foo') }.to output("foo\n").to_stdout_from_any_process
expect { system('echo foo', out: :err) }.to output("foo\n").to_stderr_from_any_process
```

The use of `Regexp.quote` is taken from [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/150095/3784008). Basically, without it you can't do proper string interpolation within the regex's `//`.