# Using variable in regex

Tags: ruby, morse-code

I'm trying to modify a binary string. Problem is that the base of the 1s in the string is variable. So it could be that I have 11 that should become 1, but also 111 to become 1 depending on a timeUnit. The timeUnit is longest consecutive '1's divided by 3 (max symbol length = 3 timeUnits).

I tried to replace the 1s with string.gsub!(/1{timeUnit}+/,"1").

In my test if I hard code a number I get the expected string back but I want it to be dynamic.

Is what I am trying to establish possible?

Comment: Regexp literals support interpolation in the same way double quoted strings do so I thing you are looking for`/1{#{timeUnit}}+/`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interpolating a string into a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150095/interpolating-a-string-into-a-regex)