# Find exact word in string and not partial

Tags: ruby

I have the following string

```
str = "feminino blue"
```

I need to know if there is a string called "mini" inside this string.
When I use include? method, the return is true because "feMINino" has "min"
Is there a way to search for the exact word that is passed as param?

Thanks

Comment: I assume the answer to your first question is "yes", but you should clarify that. You should also show how you are using [String#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F). `"feminino blue".include?('mini') #=> true` and (contrary to what you said) `"feMINino blue".include?('mini') #=> false`...

Comment: If you are actually asking, "I need to know if there is the *word* "mini" inside this string.", you can write `str.split.include?('mini')` (using [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-split) and [Array#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F)) or use a regular expression, as @Silvio has done in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a use case for [regular expressions](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Regexp.html), which can match all kinds of more complex string patterns. You can read through that page for all the specifics (and it's very valuable to learn, not just as a Ruby concept; Regexes are used in almost every modern language), but this should cover your use case.

```rb
/\bmini\b/ =~ str
```

`\b` means "match a word boundary", so exactly one of the things to the left or right should be a word character and the other side should not (i.e. should be whitespace or the beginning/end of the string).

This will return `nil` if there's no match or the index of the match if there is one. Since `nil` is falsy and all numbers are truthy, this return value is  safe to use in an `if` statement if all you need is a yes/no answer.

If the string you're working with is not constant and is instead in a variable called, say, `my_word`, you can [interpolate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150095/interpolating-a-string-into-a-regex).

```rb
/\b#{Regexp.quote(my_word)}\b/ =~ str
```

Comment: Perhaps mention [String#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F) (since v2.4) as it reads better than `=~` (and you are not making use of the offset returned by `=~` when there is a match).